# How do I link a chart item to a datagridview in VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, charts, datagridview

I am trying to get my chart to display a column graph which gets the data from a datagridview, which is connected to an xml. I am not sure what to do exactly because there is nothing that is working.

I tried using my friends code:

```
      'collects data from the XMl file "Financial_PLanner" then displays it onto a DataGrid 
    Dim MyXMlFile = "Financial_Planner.xml"
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(MyXMlFile) = True Then
        DsFinancialPlanner.ReadXml(MyXMlFile)
    End If

    'Creats a Column Graph, The X-axis of the Graph is the Data of the first Column of the DataGrid, The Y-axis of the Graph is the Data of the Second Column of the DataGrid
    graFullGraph.Series(0).ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column
    graFullGraph.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    For Count As Integer = 0 To DtabFinancialDetailsDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1
        graFullGraph.Series(0).Points.AddXY(DtabFinancialDetailsDataGridView.Item(0, Count).Value, DtabFinancialDetailsDataGridView.Item(1, Count).Value)
    Next
```

But it displays this error:
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: xValue'

It would be great if someone could help out with this! Thank you!

Comment: Would really help if you said exactly where you’re hitting that exception,  guessing xValue is column in your data table, is it possible that you have a null value in there.  If that’s the case you need to decide what is the proper way to deal with it in your situation.  Maybe don’t display that row or treat it a zero, your choice

Comment: The grid is not "connected to an XML". You are populating a `DataSet` from an XML file and you are presumably binding the `DataSet` to the grid. You should be using that same `DataSet` or, more likely, a `DataTable` within it, as the data source for the chart. The grid and the chart don't need to know anything about each other.

Comment: The code after the IF should be inside the IF.  If File doesn't exist you should be trying to fill the DGV.